# Trigonometric equation: $\sin(z)=2$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Someone could help me solve the equation   $\sin(z)=2$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** We have
$$\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}.$$
Let $w=e^{iz}$. Then our equation is 
$$\frac{w+\frac{1}{w}}{2}=2.$$
Multiply through by $2w$. We get a *quadratic equation*.